# error: package org.apache.kafka.clients.producer does not

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka. When I run this command

```
javac -cp "C:\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\libs\kafka-clients-0.10.2.0.jar" *.java
```

I get an error message

> error: package org.apache.kafka.clients.producer does not exist

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of @Abhishek:-

First download the Kafka-clients library dependencies from
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients

Copy the `org` folder and paste it in the `lib` folder of our main Kafka directory.

Then Run the above two given commands

Also It can be run by simple commands :-

```
javac -cp libs *.java

java -cp libs SimpleProducer *topicname*
```

Answer (score 1):

The following command works well

```
javac -classpath ".;C:\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\libs\kafka-clients-0.10.2.0.jar;" *.java
```

But actually we should use the following to compile

```
javac -classpath ".;C:\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\libs\*;" *.java
```

and to run the class file this

```
java -classpath ".;C:\kafka\kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0\libs\*;" SimpleProducer topicname
```